# Indentation in Visual Studio 2010 for C++ using Visual Assist X

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation, visual-assist

I've come acrossed something annoying about indentation in C++ (using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Assist X).

The thing is that every time I want to start a new line after keying in `ctrl+enter` and `ctrl+shift+enter`, the cursor begins at the very beginning of a new line. This fact annoys me a lot when using the hotkeys inside any braces. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    std::cout << "say something" /* press `ctrl+shift+enter` here*/ << std::endl;
!   |<--
}
```

After pressing the hotkey (somewhere not at the end of the line, e.g., at the comment `/*...*/` above), the cursor will be at the starting position (see `!` in the above code). What I want is to automatically put the cursor in the new line with the same indentation of the previous line (see `|<--`).

How can I make this happen? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer from [Whole Tomato Software Support Forum](http://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?whichpage=1&TOPIC_ID=10899)